# Angular and CouchDB Authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, authentication, couchdb

I am new to both angularJs and CouchDB, the question I have is about user authentication. Allowing users to login and logout is the idea. I have come from a LAMP background and understand how to do this using PHP and MySQL. Search for rows in the database and if exist create a session/cookie. I do not understand how to achieve the same think with AngularJS and CouchDB.

Most of the tutorials I have come across use node as well and this is not an option for me. I was told by a lecture of mine that I should place each new user in the _user of the couchDB but do not understand what to do once this is done. I am not asking for anyone to do my work, would just like a push in the correct direction. Either the process and methods that I need to go through or a tutorial/explanation.

Comment: I haven't implemented this myself, unfortunately, but I've been reading about how to do manage CouchDB and auth, and I'd suggest having a look at this project: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication . The Github page has a nice section on "CouchDB authentication recipes", ie. how to approach different situations, and if you can grok the code it probably provides enough info to solve your issues. Otherwise the docs include a section on http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html , and you're probably looking for something like the Cookie auth to have sessions.